# batch file - use of variable

Tags: windows, batch-file

```
@echo off
set filename = 
cd GWConfig_TDS-mtpe3003
set filename = VCU17_CCU6\applications\VCU17APP 
GOTO CHECKFILE

:CHECKFILE 
echo reached
IF EXIST %filename% ( echo exists 
) ELSE ( echo Doesnot exist )
```

/////////////////////////////////////////////////

Here output shows :

```
reached
```

Doesnot echo "exists" or "Doesnot exist"

Is there anything wrong with the use of variable "filename".

Also,

```
@echo off
set filename = 
cd GWConfig_TDS-mtpe3003
set filename = VCU17_CCU6\applications\VCU17APP 
GOTO CHECKFILE

:CHECKFILE 
echo reached
IF EXIST VCU17_CCU6\applications\VCU17APP ( echo exists 
) ELSE ( echo Doesnot exist )
```

gives output:

```
reached
exists.
```

Comment: Did you try SET without spaces around the =? I don't know if dos understands whitespaces here :)

Answer (score 6):

There are two problems here. One is the space after the variable name:

```
SET filename = whatever
```

should be

```
SET filename=whatever
```

(Or you could use `%filename %` later, but that's just horrible :)

The second problem is that without any quotes, your "IF" test won't work properly if `%filename%` is empty. Quote it instead:

```
IF EXIST "%filename%" ( echo exists
) ELSE ( echo Doesnot exist )
```

Comment: Yuck, indeed, the variable name has a trailing space. That's just awful. I banish spaces around `=` out of habit, never noticed that it has consequences for the variable name too.

Answer (score 2):

I don't have the time to properly re-create this now, but I can spot a few potential problems:

- Have you tried removing the spaces around the `=` in `set`:

  ```
  set filename=VCU17_CCU6\applications\VCU17APP
  ```

  otherwise you might have a single space leading your file name
- You might want to try to quote the use of `%filename%`:

  ```
  IF EXIST "%filename%" ( ...
  ```